# Using Intel's PMU library to profile the number of cache hits/misses

Tags: c++, performance, caching, intel

Is it possible to use Intel's PMU library to count the number of cache hits/misses for a specific snippet of code within a C program? The counts seem to be polluted by other applications running on the system.

Does the library support isolating the cache statistics that correspond to one particular snippet of code alone (ie, without interference from other applications running on the system)?

This is the snippet of code I've been testing with

```
SystemCounterState before = getSystemCounterState();

SystemCounterState after = getSystemCounterState();

cout << "===========================================================" << endl;
cout << "Instructions per Clock: " << getIPC(before, after) <<
    "\nL2 cache hits: " << getL2CacheHits(before, after) <<
    "\nL2 cache misses: " << getL2CacheMisses(before, after) <<
    "\nL2 cache hit ratio: " << getL2CacheHitRatio(before, after) <<
    "\nL3 cache hits: " << getL3CacheHits(before, after) <<
    "\nL3 cache misses: " << getL3CacheMisses(before, after) <<
    "\nL3 cache hit ratio: " << getL3CacheHitRatio(before, after) <<
    "\nWasted cycles caused by L3 misses: " << getCyclesLostDueL3CacheMisses(before, after) <<
    "\nBytes read from DRAM: " << getBytesReadFromMC(before, after) << endl;
cout << "===========================================================" << endl;
```

And these are the stats I get (Note that although I dont do any computation, the cache hit/miss counts are high):

```
===========================================================
Instructions per Clock: 0.410805
L2 cache hits: 2677
L2 cache misses: 2658
L2 cache hit ratio: 0.501781
L3 cache hits: 2151
L3 cache misses: 507
L3 cache hit ratio: 0.809255
Wasted cycles caused by L3 misses: 0.0242752
Bytes read from DRAM: 514048
===========================================================
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just printing "Printing no computation at all" is in fact doing computation.

You are calling the C++ routine 'cout' which results in quite a bit of code executing.  If you want to see this, compile this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;

    i = 1;
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    i = 2;
}
```

Use gdb, set a breakpoint on the cout, then do the 'stepi' command.  You will see how many instructions are executed when doing a 'cout'.

All of these instructions executing access memory both the instructions themselves and the data the instructions use, which can lead to quite a number of cache misses.

You might want to try grabbing the counters without doing any printing.

Comment: Sure. Of course. Sorry for the confusion. I had tried without the 'cout' part as well and still had non-zero cache stats. Just ended up pasting the wrong iteration of the code. Its been edited above.

Comment: Hi, the counts you are seeing may be due to the execution of the performance monitoring code itself, because the code and data isn't in the caches.  Try executing the before and after code twice.